# How to build EclipseLink 2.7.0

Tags: java, maven, eclipselink, maven-3, tycho

I downloaded eclipselink from here https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime. There are a lot of subprojects in it. Some of them can be built using maven, some with ant and some with gradle.

However, `org.eclipse.persistence.core` which I want to build is maven project. But when I try to build it (either parent project) I get exception:

```
Scanning for projects...
Computing target platform for MavenProject: org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/TEMP/eclipselink.runtime-master/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql/pom.xml
Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20130827064939/repository/ (0B at 0B/s)
Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20130827064939/repository
Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/ (0B at 0B/s)
Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna
Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/201406250900/ (0B at 0B/s)
Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/201409261001/ (0B at 0B/s)
Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/201501121000/ (0B at 0B/s)
Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/201502271000/ (0B at 0B/s)
Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/TEMP/eclipselink.runtime-master/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql/pom.xml
Resolving class path of MavenProject: org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/TEMP/eclipselink.runtime-master/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql/pom.xml
Computing target platform for MavenProject: org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/TEMP/eclipselink.runtime-master/foundation/org.eclipse.persistence.core/pom.xml
Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/TEMP/eclipselink.runtime-master/foundation/org.eclipse.persistence.core/pom.xml
{osgi.os=linux, osgi.ws=gtk, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true, osgi.arch=x86_64}
Cannot resolve project dependencies:
  Software being installed: org.eclipse.persistence.core 2.7.0.qualifier
  Missing requirement: org.eclipse.persistence.core 2.7.0.qualifier requires 'bundle org.eclipse.persistence.antlr 3.5.2' but it could not be found

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Dependency_Resolution_Troubleshooting for help.
Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/TEMP/eclipselink.runtime-master/foundation/org.eclipse.persistence.core/pom.xml: See log for details -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: 
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MavenExecutionException
```

The jar `org.eclipse.persistence.antlr` `3.5.2` is already in zip I downloaded and there are besides sources of it, which can be built using ant.
And I could add this jar as dependency but I don't think this is the right way - because there are a lot of jars inside this zip file.

**Question**: how to build it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed the `pom.xml` files are misleading, these projects are not Maven projects or - at least - are not meant to be built directly via maven. The whole build is an **ant** build which makes uses of Maven as a supporting tool because of the need of using Tycho integration.

Looking at the [`antbuild.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/d64337fda8c6e2ef9fa860bcfbf3fcde573c685e/antbuild.xml) ant build file, you would see it is invoking Maven via its Java main class (Maven is built in Java and the entry point is an old plain Java main after all): `org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher`, in its [`build-core`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/master/antbuild.xml#L553) target.

So the workflow is:

- Start an ant build, from the root folder, invoking `ant -f antbuild.xml`
- Ant will then invoke Maven builds as nested builds
- Nested Maven builds are on multi-module/aggregator projects, which in turn will build several Maven modules (sub-projects), starting form the root/parent Maven `pom.xml` located under `buildsystem/org.eclipse.persistence.parent`

Note you would need to have:

- **Maven 3** to build it, as a `prerequisites` of the aforementioned parent pom file.
- the `M2_HOME` env variable set, pointing at your maven installation folder
- Use Ant **1.9**+

---

However, as part of the minimal set-up, the default build would not run properly (successfully), because of `junit` missing library, as specified by the `echo` statement below:

```
[echo] junit.lib = '${junit.lib}' (if not set tests may not compile; let alone run)
```

Hence, the minimal invocation would be:

```
ant -f antbuild.xml -Djunit.lib=<path_to_junit_jar>
```

For instance, you could directly point to your maven repository as following (which worked for me):

```
ant -f antbuild.xml -DC:\data\m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar
```

alternatively, you can specify the path in the [`antbuild.properties`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/master/antbuild.properties) file, [here](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/d64337fda8c6e2ef9fa860bcfbf3fcde573c685e/antbuild.properties#L5):

```
# The directory that holds the oracle-specific jar files.   
# You can either put the jars in this directory, or specify your own directory.   
junit.lib=../extension.lib.external/junit.jar
```

The same should also be made for `jmockit`, otherwise causing some compilation errors, althought not affecting a successful build.

The `jmockit.jar` property can be set in the [`antbuild.properties`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/d64337fda8c6e2ef9fa860bcfbf3fcde573c685e/moxy/eclipselink.moxy.test/antbuild.properties) file of the [`eclipse.moxy.test`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/tree/d64337fda8c6e2ef9fa860bcfbf3fcde573c685e/moxy/eclipselink.moxy.test) module, [here](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/d64337fda8c6e2ef9fa860bcfbf3fcde573c685e/moxy/eclipselink.moxy.test/antbuild.properties#L67):

```
#JMockit   
jmockit.jar=jmockit-1.10.jar
```

Or, again, via command line as per the following example:

```
ant -f antbuild.xml -Djunit.lib=C:\data\m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar -Djmockit.jar=C:\data\m2\repository\org\jmockit\jmockit\1.10\jmockit-1.10.jar
```

The command above gave me a successful build, no compilation errors at all. Only warnings were present concerning usage of deprecated or internal API.

Comment: I did as you wrote, but I get `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:0.23.0:compile (default-compile) on project org.eclipse.persistence.nosql: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
     [java] [ERROR] /home/TEMP/eclipselink.runtime-master/foundation/org.eclipse.persistence.nosql/src/org/eclipse/persistence/eis/adapters/jms/JMSEISConnectionSpec.java:[1]`

Comment: @JimJim2000 I got build successful, althought just noticed some compilation errors concerning Mockito, I will update the answer accordingly. However, the `nosql` module was build successfully and the compilation error did not affect the final build result, I will investigate it further

Answer (score 2):

You may use [this guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Building) for building EclipseLink.

Some elements may be outdated but you should have no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have got same type of problem in one project. There was a parent project. There is another project also. But they are dependent on each other. What I have to do to make it runnable is given below.

You must have identify which one need to be build first. Then next, then next. If you have no documentation, then it is tough and time consuming to identify.

### Another thing:

The minimum requirement to run `EclipseLink 2.7.0` is `Java 8`. Please ensure that you have `Java 8` installed and it's working.

Comment: why do you think the minimum requirement is **Java 8**?, according to the Eclipselink documentation it is **JDK 1.6.0 or higher**: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/solutions/install001.htm#CHDFACCB

Comment: My bad, on further testing the eclipselink xjc with JDK 1.7 I get a **org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/xjc/MOXyXJC : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0** error - that "official" documentation must be incorrect. It works after changing **JAVA_HOME** env var to point to JDK 1.8.